# alignof(double) in MSVC win32

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-alignment

The following code (msvc 2012, 32bit):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double d;
    std::cout<<_alignof(double)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<((size_t)(&d)) % _alignof(double)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output is sometime:

```
8
0
```

but, sometime it's :

```
8
4
```

Doesn't alignof(double)=8 means that double's alignment will be 8?

Iv'e seen :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290049(v=vs.71).aspx
but i'm not sure i understand that...

Comment: Your text says `alignof` but your code says `_alignof` (and the linked site talks about yet another `__alignof`), about which are we talking here? I could imagine them having subtle differences.

Comment: The article tells you that the stack is aligned to 4 for 32-bit code and that the compiler will make an effort to align to 8 when necessary.  Core issue is that you didn't give it enough reason to do this.  You actually have to *use* the variable to get it to align.  You'll know you're ahead when you see `and         esp,0FFFFFFF8h` in the generated code.

Comment: I've tried to use the variable. It's still not 8-byte aligned.

Comment: About the difference between alignof (c++11 spec) and __alignof (microsoft's); I think that this is the real answer - microsoft did not implement the spec's alignof, and called a similar function __alignof. Microsoft's function return alignment of a variable inside a struct and not alignment of local and global variables.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you take the address on stack (&d), which start address is dynamically calculated when your program starts. _alignof(double) will always return 8, because for base types it's the same as they sizes.

Comment: His question is probably why the variable on the stack is not aligned in the way he thinks it should be.

Comment: Which implies that `_alignof` yields something other than the actual required alignment of the type.

Comment: Well, the spec (c++11) says about alignment - "...restrictions on the addresses at which an object of that type may be allocated.". Does it refer only to dynamic allocation?